# css and javascript under functions.php not working from WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

// calling styles

function calling_resources(){

// Slider for css

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'css', get_template_directory_uri() . './assets/css/flex-slider.css', '', '1.0.0');
```

// Fontawsome css for icons

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'css', get_template_directory_uri() . './assets/css/fontawesome.css', '', '1.0.0');
```

// Bootstrap for styling layouts

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'css', get_template_directory_uri() . './vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', '', '1.0.0');

wp_enqueue_style( 'css', get_template_directory_uri() . './vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', '', '1.0.0');
```

// Core style.css

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri());
```

// Bootstrap core JavaScript

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() , '/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js', array ( 'jquery'), 1.0, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array ( ), 1.0, true);
```

// Additional Scripts

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array ( ), 1.0, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.js', array ( ), 1.0, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.js', array ( ), 1.0, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/accordions.js', array ( ), 1.0, true);
```

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'calling_resources');

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your getting the right URI? The wordpress funtions state that the passed URI parameter is relative to the wordpress root directory.